# document.write ignored before DOMContentLoaded while waiting for high-latency script to load

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, domready

I've tried many different ways to phrase this question to google et al with no luck. Not even sure the title of this question captures the nuance of the issue. I'll try to explain then show the experiment. I hope someone(s) will be able to point to some explanation of what's going on.

**Given:**

- before the end of BODY, you have a script (A) that programmatically inserts a script element (using my preferred technique, document.createElement) into the document which references a remote-script (B)
- remote-script B performs a document.write of any content (e.g. "hello, world")
- before the end of BODY and just after script A you have a script (C) that references a remote-script which takes a while to load (e.g. 1s)

What will happen is that A executes, inserts B into the document and starts to download the resource. While B is downloading, C will execute and wait, because of the delay. While C is waiting, B is downloaded and executes; we have not yet hit DOMContentLoaded; document.readyState is still "loading". The document.write from B is ignored; gobbled up, as if we are post-DOMContentLoaded. C then finishes downloading and executes.

**Experiment:**

- Source: http://jsfiddle.net/jaknowlden/pwHG8/
- Try it out directly: http://jsfiddle.net/jaknowlden/pwHG8/show/
- Waterfall: MANUAL LINK[cl.ly/423P2M1d0r0e0k3h370g]
- Remote script: MANUAL LINK[thumblemonks.com/js/stackoverflow-script-b.js]

I am using Cuzillion to create the delay. If you check out the waterfall image, you'll also see the console.log message, which shows that everything is executed before the DOM hits "interactive" readyState (i.e. DOMContentLoaded).

What I expect as output in the browser is:

```
TOP
hello, world
hello again, world
BOTTOM
```

What I get as output is:

```
TOP
hello, world
BOTTOM
```

You'll notice in my experiment that I have added another script between what we would define as A and C. Call this A' I suppose; it shows that if you dynamically add a script that has text (i.e. not a remote script) which contains a document.write, the doc.write in A' WILL work.

Also, dummy.js and the CSS files come from JSFiddle. They are not the culprits; I can recreate this issue anywhere.

Things I know:

- if you replace C with an IMG, there is no issue
- if you replace C with an IFRAME, there is no issue
- if you move A after C, there is no issue

**Now:**

Perhaps there is a perfectly valid reason for this. There must be since all of the browsers I've tested in seem to behave in roughly the same way. What I'd like to know is why? Any explanations, hints, and/or pointers are welcome. Even hints like "It's in the spec, dumby :)" I've got thick skin; I can handle it.

DISCLAIMER: I abhor document.write. My intention is not to support or bolster its use in any way. However, given the nature of my work, I have to work around it for now and this oddity sprung itself on me. Thus, I'd like to avoid comments along the line of "you shouldn't use document.write" because this, I already believe in :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing document.write from async-loaded scripts is not supported in HTML5, precisely because it's racy: you have no way to know whether your script will run before or after DOMContentLoaded.  See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#ignore-destructive-writes-counter and http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#dom-document-write step 2 and http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#execute-the-script-block step 3.  The point being that having the write work if the script beats the race to DOMContentLoaded but be ignored if it loses the race would be pretty odd and would lead to pages sometimes working and sometimes not depending on network conditions.

Comment: Thanks, @boris-zbarksy. Great pointers. Should have probably started with these specs. They'll help while moving through the webkit source code. I haven't finished breaking down all of the conditions, but in response to your assertion about what the DOM should do I ask: why does script A execute fine when moved after script C? It's only when it's before C that this is a problem. Again, I don't actually want document.write to work, I'm more curious about what is going on here.

Comment: So, when C comes before A, then B (which is loaded by A) actually gets to wait until parsing-finished. That would explain a destructive write being ignored in that case. But I guess I just have to accept that the browser will execute A (when it comes before C) knowing parsing is not finished - [since readyState is not yet interactive](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-end.html#the-end) - but will still treat the document as closed. Bit of a weird race condition, IMO.

Comment: @Gus I wouldn't expect that changing the order of A and C in your setup would affect anything.  Can you post a link to a version with A and C reversed?

Comment: [the source](http://jsfiddle.net/jaknowlden/pwHG8/19/)  and the [resulting page](http://jsfiddle.net/jaknowlden/pwHG8/19/show). The document.write still doesn't work (obviously), but you'll notice we hit the interactive readyState now; whereas in the previous example, we are still in "loading". Your pointer to the [ignore-destructive-writes-counter](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#ignore-destructive-writes-counter) mostly explains it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  A slow non-async script will affect the readyState, of course, because it blocks the parser and the switch to the interactive readyState happens when parsing of the document completes.  I thought you meant that the changed order affected the document.write behavior, which would be odd.

Comment: It's actually quite obvious now that I think about it. Problem was that I was backing into the issue. Thanks for the redirection help, @boris-zbarsky.

Comment: if a external script element do not have `async`and `defer`,its`ignore-destructive-writes counter` is more than zero,but the document write is allowed, this why?

Comment: @SKing7 Becuase if the insertion point is defined (i.e. this is a parser-inserted script tag), the write is not destructive.  See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-write step 3.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky why the insertion point of blocking script is defined , but the script has defer or async is not defined ? what is the difference between block script and async/defer script on insertion point?

Comment: @SKing7 The insertion point is maintained by the parser.  Specifically when it sees the `</script>`.  See <https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#scriptEndTag>.  For a non-inline script, the "pending parsing-blocking script" bits will do the same thing when the script is ready to run (see steps 6 and 8 under "Otherwise"). But that only applies to parsing-blocking scripts, which means not scripts using async or defer.

Comment: the `pending parsing-blocking script` refers to the blocking script?

Comment: @SKing7 It refers to a script that blocks further parsing until it has run.

Answer (score 0):

> SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/gist/2141272/1a6bf0111ce10d55e628e3736a9d381d82e8a780/external-with-docwrite.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch

This is your problem. The script is transferred as `text/plain`, which is not a valid MIME type for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, Kolink. That's just a function of your browser, however. In Chrome, this executes. I was trying to keep the source for everyone to see, but I have moved this file to one of my servers and updated the Fiddle. Can you try again.